# How to delete a sub directory out of many directories using shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I want to delete a subdirectory which can be in any of the directories using shell script

For eg 
The main directory has 3 directories a , b and c  and the test folder can be in any of the 3 directories ie a , b, c. so now i want to delete the test directory.So how can we do this

Comment: Just try to delete `a/test`, `b/test` *and* `c/test`. If the directory doesn't exist, it won't be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have different options to do it but i like use the [globstar](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option):

```
rm -r **/subfolder
```

Full example:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ mkdir foo
$ cd foo/
$ mkdir -p bar/zzz
$ mkdir -p bar/aaa
$ mkdir -p bar/bbb
$ mkdir -p xxx/aaa
$ mkdir -p xxx/ccc
$ mkdir -p xxx/ddd
$ rm -r **/aaa
$ ls
bar  xxx
```

Comment: That does not seem very effective if the subdirectory is nested below two or more subdirectories

Comment: That's rigth ecelis but i do not agree with the downvote as the question seems clear about the nested level

Comment: I apologize, the down vote wasn't because the answer was wrong. It answers the question yes, but could be better.

Answer (score 1):

From within main directory:

```
find . -type d -name 'test' -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find and then delete it like this:

```
find . -name test -type d -print0|xargs -0 rm -r --
```

Answer (score 0):

using `find`:

```
find -type d -a -name test
```

will list all directories with name `test`, then you can

```
find -type d -a -name test|xargs rm -r
```

to remove

Answer (score 0):

If your directories are so similar, you don't need a complex `find` pipeline, you can use pathname expansion directly:

```
$ rm -r [abc]/test
```